# Convolution of $f(2x)$ and $g(3x)$

Tags: functions, convolution

As I know, convolution is defined as $f(x)*g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\tau)g(x-\tau)d_{\tau}$, but what if we want to convolve $f(2x)$ and $g(3x)$? It should be like $f(2x)*g(3x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(2\tau)g(3x-\tau)d_{\tau}$ or $f(2x)*g(3x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(2\tau)g(3x-3\tau)d_{\tau}$ or anything else?

Comment: The latter is correct.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2010996/14578, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/35479/5874.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $f(2x)*g(3x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(2\tau)g(3x-3\tau)d\tau $

Comment: Note that if we say $f_0(x) = f(x)$ and $g_0(x) = g(3x)$, then $f_0*g_0 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_0(\tau)g_0(x-\tau) d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(2\tau)g(3(x-\tau))d\tau$.